# Make 2-D numpy arrays from regular grid without excess memory use

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.4, mayavi

Many of the plotting functions I use to visualize data (`plot_surface`, `plot_wireframe`, mayavi's `contour3`, etc.) take as arguments 2-D arrays `X, Y, Z`, and some scalar value of the function.

I usually have information from a file in the format

```
x   y   z   data
0   0   1    45
...
```

Which is on a regular grid. I have way too many values to be able to hold the output from meshgrid in my memory, but I can hold the full dataset as either an `Nx4` or four `Nx1` arrays.

Is there a way to make a view, or restructure the existing gridded data to a format that is compatible with these functions?

I realize that I can use `griddata` and interpolate to lower the resolution, and that is my current approach.

UPDATE:

The specific task I'm working on uses mayavi's `contour3` function to generate an isosurface plot, but the approach of multidimensionalizing the arrays should be general.

Comment: How about non-gridded plots like `scatter`, `pcolor`?

Comment: Those work for some kinds of data, but I would like to take advantage of the fact that my data is already on a regular grid. Also, neither of those would work for the 3d + value example

Comment: Meshgrid takes  a `copy` keyword argument, see the docs. Though I don't understand how you run out of memory for the output of meshgrid but *can* hold a `Nx4` array. If the 2D arrays have dimensions `[a, b]` then `a*b == N` right?

Comment: @morningsun for a 2D array, `meshgrid` returns two arrays of shape `[a,a]`, not `[a,b]`. Even worse in 3D, `[a,a,a] == a*a*a== N**3`

Comment: @morningsun Make your comment an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly reduce memory use by passing `copy=False` to meshgrid. This creates views into the original arrays, [see the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)